# Question about HMM

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I have this HMM model that I need to solve. Unfortunately, my textbook isn't the best and only describes general cases which I have difficulty working with.

Consider an HMM with two states: s1 and s2. The transition model is: $P(s_1|s_1) = 0.5$, $P(s_1|s_2) = 0.25$. There are two observations: $P(a|s_1) = 0.25$ and $P(a|s_2) = 0.5$. The initial state is $s_1$ at time $0$.

How would I find the predicted distribution over these two states at time $2$?

Comment: This seems to ask for the distribution of the state process at time 2, which does not involve the HMM structure and puts weights .375 on state s1 and .625 on state s2.

Comment: This would be the case where we have not made any observations correct?

Comment: Let $Z(t) \in \{s_1, s_2\}$ be the state of your system at time $t \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$.  Let $a(t) \in \{0,1\}$ be the binary "observation" on slot $t$, so that $Pr[a(t)=1|Z(t)=s_1]=0.25, Pr[a(t)=1|Z(t)=s_2]=0.5$.  Given that $Z(0)=s_1$, we do not care about observation $a(0)$. Then the probability distribution of $Z(2)$ depends on $a(1)$ and $a(2)$, so there are 4 possibilities.  The Did answer above indeed ignores observations, or, equivalently, averages over all possible observations.

Comment: And that is how we get 0.375 for s1 and 0.625 for s2?

Comment: If you ignore observations this is not an HMM problem, it is just a standard Markov chain problem.  Take the transition probability matrix $P$ and square it.  Yes, that will give you the .375 and .625.

Comment: Oh ok that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: What about if the observation at t=1 is a, and t=2 is b. What is the distribution when t=2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume discrete time $t \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$.  Let $Z(t)$ be the value of your Markov chain, so $Z(t) \in \{s_1, s_2\}$.   Let $R(t)$ be the observation on slot $t$ (assume $R(t) \in \{a,b\}$).   Assume that $Pr[R(t)=a|Z(t)=s_1] = 0.25$, $Pr[R(t)=a|Z(t)=s_2]=0.5$. 
Let $H(t)$ be the history of observations up to time $t$: 
$$ H(t) = [R(0), R(1), \ldots, R(t)] $$

Define:

\begin{align} 
P_1(t) &= Pr[Z(t)=s_1 | H(t)] \\
P_2(t) &= Pr[Z(t)=s_2 | H(t)] 
\end{align} 
Note that $P_1(t) + P_2(t) = 1$ for all $t$, and $P_1(0) = 1, P_2(0)=0$.

You want a recursive way to update $P_1(t+1)$ given $P_1(t)$ and given the new observation $R(t+1)$.  You can use Baye’s rule.  Suppose for example that $R(t+1)=a$.  We get:

\begin{align} 
P_1(t+1) &= Pr[Z(t+1)=s_1 | R(t+1)=a, H(t)] \\
&= \frac{Pr[R(t+1)=a|Z(t+1)=s_1, H(t)]Pr[Z(t+1)=s_1|H(t)]}{Pr[R(t+1)=a|H(t)]} \\
&= \frac{0.25Pr[Z(t+1)=s_1|H(t)]}{Pr[R(t+1)=a|H(t)]} 
\end{align}

where: 
\begin{align}
Pr[Z(t+1) = s_1|H(t)] &= 0.5P_1(t) + 0.25P_2(t) \\
Pr[Z(t+1) = s_2|H(t)] &= 0.5P_1(t) + 0.75P_2(t)
\end{align} 
and: 
$$ Pr[R(t+1)=a|H(t)] = Pr[Z(t+1)=s_1|H(t)]0.25 + Pr[Z(t+1)=s_2|H(t)]0.5$$

---

So if you are given that $R(1)=a$ then you update: 
\begin{align} 
Pr[Z(1)=s_1|H(0)] &= (0.5)(1) + 0 = 0.5\\
Pr[Z(1)=s_2|H(0)] &= 0.5\\
Pr[R(1)=a|H(0)] &= (0.5)(0.25) + (0.5)(0.5) = 0.3750\\
P_1(1) &= \frac{(0.25)(0.5)}{0.3750} = 1/3\\
P_2(1) &= 2/3
\end{align}

If you are next given that $R(2)=b$ then you do a similar update to find: 
\begin{align} 
Pr[Z(2)=s_1|H(1)] &= ??\\
Pr[Z(2)=s_2|H(1)] &= ??\\
Pr[R(2)=b|H(1)] &= ??\\
P_1(2) &= ??\\
P_2(2) &= ??
\end{align}

Comment: So that would be: 1/3, 2/3, 0.6250, (0.5*1/3)/0.6250?

Comment: I agree $Pr[Z(2)=s_1|H(1)]=1/3$, $Pr[Z(2)=s_2|H(1)]=2/3$ but I get $Pr[R(2)=b|H(1)]=7/12 \approx .5833$.  Do you agree?

Comment: Notice in my answer above I say "Suppose for example $R(t+1)=a$."  The formulas I give are for that case.  You need to derive similar formulas for the case  "Suppose $R(t+1)=b$."

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I understand. Thanks! I'll work on it

Comment: Hey, so I've finally got back around do it. P(R(2)=b) = (1/3)(1/4)+(2/3)(3/4). 

Then, P_1(2) = (3/16)/(7/12) = 0.3414 and P_2(2) = 0.67857.

Is that right?

How do you then get the smoothed state distribution at time t=1 if we've just observed 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: What formula are you using for $Pr[R(t+1)=b|H(t)]$?  Your answer is 7/12 which is the same as mine, but I cannot follow the numbers you are multiplying, I wonder if they accidentally give the same answer as the numbers I am multiplying.  Also, what formula are you using for $P_1(t+1)$ in the case when $R(t+1)=b$?